# update con left join en Laravel no me funciona!

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola quisiera hacer un update con left join. mi objetivo es copiar los valores de una tabla a otra tabla de mysql, pero hacerlo de una forma legible en laravel.

Estoy haciendo esto (funciona) pero se ve muy feo

```
DB::connection('db')->statement('update t1 left join t2 set t1.col = t2.col where t1.id = t2.id');
```

intente esto pero no me funciona (quisiera tener algo asi que funcione):

```
Model::where('t1.id_currency', 't2.id_currency')
                ->leftJoin('t2', 't2.id_currency', '=', 't1.id_currency')
                ->update(['t1.conversion_rate' => \DB::raw('t2.conversion_rate')]);
```

le hice db:enablequerylog para ver la query y se supone que tiene que estar bien. No se que estoy haciendo mal, pero no actualiza nada

Comment: Hi there, you are at [es.so]. Please translate your question to spanish. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano. Además, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**Comentario 1**

Tal parece que tu consulta usa una conexión distinta a la que maneja Laravel de forma predeterminada.

Y ya que planeas usar al modelo para construir la query, entonces lo mas simple es declarar esta conexión personalizada [como propiedad](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) del ya mencionado así:

```
class Modelo extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'db';
}
```

Entonces cuando se componga y ejecute la consulta esta apuntará a la bd de la conexión declarada.

**Comentario 2**

Aunque mencionas que no falla, la forma en que compones la consulta para actualizar valores no me parece del todo correcta, ya que si estás usando un join (en este caso un `leftJoin`), entonces de forma inicial no dependes de un `where` para la comparación de claves pues eso se logra con la [clausula on](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html), entonces tu consulta debería verse así:

```
UPDATE t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.col = t2.col
```

**Comentario 3**

Entonces para tu consulta dentro de Laravel la podemos dejar así:

```
Modelo::leftJoin('t2', 't2.id_currency', '=', 't1.id_currency')
            ->update(['t1.conversion_rate' => 't2.conversion_rate']);
```

Lo que cambié fue que:

- Ya no necesitas al método `where()` pues la comparación de claves se esta llevando a cabo dentro del método `leftJoin` desde el 2do. hasta al 4to. parámetro.
- No veo la necesidad (*y por eso lo removí*) del uso de [DB::raw()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions) pues no estás pasando ninguna consulta en SQL pura que así deba ser interpretada.

Comment: siempre acostumbro a usar 'where' en update, pensaba que era una buena practica